# Practical book in C

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum, reference-request

Is there any practical “go to” book that demonstrates the main dsp methods for time series written in C for practical applications? (Doesn’t have to be for hardware, but for any raw data such as sensors, stocks, etc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a single book on C programming with DSP, then I would refer to the classical one

*C (Language) Algorithms for Real-Time DSP*

from Paul M. Embree. And as far as I know, there is no modern version to beat it's simplicity, clarity and usefulness...

Comment: Hard to get outside US. Any modern alternative?

Comment: New prints may not be available. The newer C++ version is available and as far as I can see it ships outside US via Amazon. I believe the C vs C++ (from DSP perspecive) won't be a big difference.

Comment: i should get that book.